# Cluster similar curves considering "belongingness"?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, similarity

Currently, I have 6 curves shown in 6 different colors as below.
[image]
The 6 curves are in fact generated by 6 trials of **one same experiment**. That means, ideally they should be the same curve, but due to the noise and different trial participants, they just look similar but not exactly the same.

Now I wish to create an algorithm that is able to identify that the 6 curves are essentially the same and cluster them together into one cluster. **What similarity metrics should I use?**

**Note:**

1. The `x-axis` does **NOT** matter at all! I simply align them together for visual purpose. Thus, feel free to left/right shift the curves, if doing so helps.
2. "Sub-curves" that are part of the curves may appear. The "belongingness" is important and thus needs identifying as well. But again, left/right shifting is allowed.

I have attemped to learn some of the clustering algorithm, such as DBSCAN, K-means, Fuzzy C-means, etc. But I don't see their appropriateness in this case, because the "belongingness" needs to be spotted!

*Any suggestions or comments are well welcomed. I understand that it is hard to give some exact solutions to this question. I am only expecting some enlightening suggestions here.*

Comment: If you discretize along x, you get a vector of values that you can use with Euclidean distance (or any other standard metric).

Comment: This question might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820814/trajectory-clustering-which-clustering-method?rq=1

Comment: @larsmans sorry I didn't get it. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at **time series similarity functions**, such as dynamic time warping.

They can be used with e.g. DBSCAN but NOT with k-means (you cannot compute a reasonable "mean" for these distances; k-means is really designed for squared Euclidean distances).

Comment: DTW is a really really awesome suggestion here!

Comment: Enlightened by your answer, I have tried DTW but encountered with the following question. Could you please further take a look and help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887200/x-invariant-dynamic-time-warping