# mlpy - Dynamic Time Warping depends on x?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching, data-mining

I am trying to get the distance between these two arrays shown below by DTW. 
[image]

I am using the Python `mlpy` package that offers

```
dist, cost, path = mlpy.dtw_std(y1, y2, dist_only=False)
```

I understand that DTW does take care of the "shifting". In addition, as can be seen from above, the `mlpy.dtw_std()` only takes in 2 1-D arrays. So I expect that no matter how I left/right shift my curves, the `dist` returned by the function should never change.

*However after shifting my green curve a bit to the right, the `dist` returned by `mlpy.dtw_std()` changes!*

**Before shifting: Python `mlpy.dwt_std` reports `dist = 14.014`**
[image]

**After shifting: Python `mlpy.dwt_std` reports `dist = 38.078`**
[image]
Obviously, since the curves are still those two curves, I don't expect the distances to be different!

**Why is it so? Where went wrong?**

Comment: how did you do the shifting ? can you show your code ? if you add 'artificial' points to the beginning of a vector, problem is those points also need to be mapped, so the final DTW value will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Let me reiterate what I have understood, please correct me if I am going wrong anywhere. I observe that in both your plots, your 1D series in blue is remaining identical, while green colored is getting stretched. How you are doing it, that you have explained it in the post on Sep 19 '13 at 9:36. Your premise is that because (1) DTW 'takes care' of time shift and (2) all that you are doing is stretching one time-series length-wise, not affecting y-values, (Inference:) you are expecting distance to remain the same.

**There is a little missing link between [(1),(2)] and [(Inference)]. Which is, individual distance values corresponding to mappings WILL change as you change set of signals itself. And this will result into difference in the overall distance computation.**  Plot the warping paths, cost grid to see it for yourself.

Let's take an oversimplified case...

Let
 `a=range(0,101,5)` = [0,5,10,15...95, 100]

and `b=range(0,101,5)` = [0,5,10,15...95, 100].

Now intuitively speaking, you/I would expect one to one correspondence between 2 signals (for DTW mapping), and distance for all of the mappings to be 0, signals being identically looking.

Now if we make, `b=range(0,101,4)` = [0,4,8,12...96,100],
DTW mapping between a and b still would start with a's 0 getting mapped to b's 0, and end at a's 100 getting mapped to b's 100 (boundary constraints). Also, because DTW 'takes care' of time shift, I would also expect 20's, 40's, 60's and 80's of the two signals to be mapped with one another. (I haven't tried DTWing these two myself, saying it from intuition, so please check. There is little possibility of non-intuitive warpings taking place as well, depending on step patterns allowed / global constraints, but let's go with intuitive warpings for the moment for the ease of understanding / sake of simplicity).

For the remaining data points, clearly, distances corresponding to mapping are now non-zero, therefore the overall distance too is non-zero. Our distance/overall cost value has changed from zero to something that is non-zero.

Now, this was the case when our signals were too simplistic, linearly increasing. Imagine the variabilities that will come into picture when you have real life non-monotonous signals, and need to find time-warping between them. :)

(PS: Please don't forget to upvote answer :D). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the curves are not identical, and therefore the distance function must not be 0 (otherwise, it is not a distance by definition).

What IS "relatively large"? The distance probably is not infinite, is it?

140 points in time, each with a small delta, this still adds up to a non-zero number.

The distance "New York" to "Beijing" is roughly 11018 km. Or 1101800000 mm.

The distance to Alpha Centauri is small, just 4.34 lj. That is the nearest other stellar system to us...

Compare with the distance to a non-similar series; that distance should be much larger.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say they are identical. But I wish the system to recognize them as similar. My problem is that imagine I shift the red curve a bit right, then I would expect the dist reported by dtw will be smaller, although it is the same red curve. I am asking how to remove the shifting effect on dwt. Thanks!

Comment: DTW should largely take care of the shifting, so this should *not* affect the similarity much, if you manually shift it.

Comment: So you mean I have to shift it manually first and then apply DTW? AFAIK, the dist reported by DTW is really affected by their relative positions.

Comment: Please kindly refer to the updated question showing how DTW changes with the shifting effects. Thanks!

Comment: How did you perform the shift? Are you doing DTW on it as a 1-dimensional (y only) series, or a 2-dimensional (x,y) series? That makes a difference, too.

Comment: 1. To be clearer, my x-axis is actually an **accumulative** distance of a robot in meter and my y-axis is its heading direction in radian. Since the x-axis is accumulative distance, so I shift the curve right by increasing the robot's every movement by 0.1m. 2. I am doing DTW on a 1-dimensional (y only) series, because the Python module only takes in y values (http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/dtw.html). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still don't get that part. If you only use the y values, how does the shifting affect the data? can you give the formula?

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what confuses me. The function indeed takes in 2 1-D arrays! But the dist returned is indeed affected by the shift as seen above. Maybe this link will help you learn more about this PyThon package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889747/two-issues-about-mlpy-dtw-package-in-python No worries even if u don't know python. It requires no python k owledege. So do please kindly help out. Thank you so much!

Comment: How does the shift change the array then?