# Two Issues about mlpy.dtw package in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

As a newbie in Dynamic Time Warping (DTW), I find its Python implementation [mlpy.dtw](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/dtw.html) is not documented in a very detailed extend. I have some problems with its return value.

Regarding the returned value `dist`? I have **two questions**:

- **Any typo here?** For standard DTW, the document says

> Standard DTW as described in [Muller07], using the **Euclidean distance
>   (absolute value of the difference)** or squared Euclidean distance (as
>   in [Keogh01]) as local cost measure.

and for subsequence DTW, the document says

> Subsequence DTW as described in [Muller07], assuming that the length
>   of y is much larger than the length of x and using the **Manhattan
>   distance (absolute value of the difference)** as local cost measure.

The same so-called "absolute value of the difference" corresponds two different distance metrics?

- **Total distance?** After running the snippet

  dist, cost, path = mlpy.dtw_std(x, y, dist_only=False)

`dist` is one value. **So is it the lumped sum of all the distances between each matched pair?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `mlpy.dtw()` function is not well documented.

- **First question:** no typo here. As you can see in the documentation, euclidean, squared euclidean and manhattan distances concern the **local cost measure**. In this case the cost measure is defined as a distance between two real values (one dimension), see *cost* in the pseudocode in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping. So, in this case, Manhattan distance and Euclidean distance are the same (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#One_dimension). Anyway, in the standard dtw, you can choose the euclidean distance (absolute value of the difference) or the squared euclidean distance (squared difference) by the parameter *squared*:

```py
>>> import mlpy
>>> mlpy.dtw_std([1,2,3], [4,5,6], squared=False) # Euclidean distance
9.0
>>> mlpy.dtw_std([1,2,3], [4,5,6], squared=True) # Squared Euclidean distance
26.0
```

- **Second question:** *dist* is the **unnormalized** minimum-distance warp path between time series x and y. It is the unnormalized DTW distance. You can normalize it dividing by len(X)+len(Y). See http://www.irit.fr/~Julien.Pinquier/Docs/TP_MABS/res/dtw-sakoe-chiba78.pdf

Cheers,
Davide

Comment: It does not address the OP doubts regarding Manhattan/Euclidean distance identical descriptions

Comment: Thanks Davide! This question is clear. But may I ask you another question? Why does the dist calculated by your package depend on the x-axis? i.e. When I x-shift my 2D array, and then the dist changes! Could you please kindly explain why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887200/x-invariant-dynamic-time-warping/

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an error in the documentation. Euclidean distance is not the "absolute value of the difference", it is the correct description of the Manhattan metric. Probably author was thinking about one dimension case, as in R both Euclidean and manhattan metrics are the same (and Euclidean metric really expresses the absolute value of the difference then). *I am not familiar with the library, if it only operates on 1 dimensional objects,  then there is no error and these two distance measures are equivalent*

The `dist` value is the value of best time-warp (measured as the summarized costs of matching, [see the algorithm definiton on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)). So it is in fact the minimum edit distance between two sequences, where particular edits' costs are expressed in dissimilarity (distance) between "matched" objects

Comment: 1. The function indeed only takes in 2 1-D array. So the two distance metrics are interchangeable? 2. So the dist is the ACCUMULATIVE distances of ALL the matched pairs?

Comment: 1. Yes, in such case EUclidean and Manhattan distance are the same thing. 2. Yes, it is accumulated as outlined in the enclosed link

Comment: Thanks! The package is still confusing me. Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887200/x-invariant-dynamic-time-warping/ if you can. :)